# ion-libel positon="floating" is not working with ion-input placeholder

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

Label isn't moving when input will be focus. If input hasn't placeholder it works fine but in my case it has a placeholder. How can I fix it?

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-label position="floating" >{{ 'enterPhoneNumber' | translate}}</ion-label>
 <ion-input placeholder="Phone" name="phone" type="text" required ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder text has to go with the ion-label tags... Please refer the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input).

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating"> Phone </ion-label>
      <ion-input required [(ngModel)]="enterPhoneNumber" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: you cannot specify placeholder="Phone", when you are already adding a floating placeholder.. use my code above and test

Comment: share your code.. this is from the docs.. and this has to work..maybe your pipe is returning null..